# Android - Check the certificate of an app

Tags: android, decompiling, decompiler

Hi
Is there any way to check the certificate of an app (e.g. [**Amazon Mobile**](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.amazon.mShop.android&feature=search_result))?
decompile the apk or whatever?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jarsigner tool from JDK.

JDKFOLDER\bin\jarsigner.exe -verify -verbose -certs myAndroidProgram.apk